# Kali update repository different to sources.list

Tags: kali-linux, repository

I did a fresh install of Kali Linux and during installation I opted to choose the best mirror, however, in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I have the following

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

But when I do `sudo apt-get update`, I see the below:

```
Hit:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@abc:~# cd /etc/apt/
```

My question, where is `http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling InRelease` coming from? and how do I get rid of this and make `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free` as my default repo

Comment: Is there anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: Absolutely empty in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/apt/apt.conf` specifying a different `sourcelist`? Or even a different configuration file (`echo $APT_CONFIG`)?

Comment: I will check this and let you know

Comment: Repo server redirects you to a mirror which is closest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How it work?](https://docs.kali.org/community/kali-linux-mirrors)

> When using the default hosts listed above, **you’ll automatically be redirected to a mirror site which is geographically close to you**, and which is guaranteed to be up-to-date.

The `http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali/` is the nearest and the best mirror for you.

As you can see on [README.mirrorlist](http://http.kali.org/README.mirrorlist) (at the bottom) , the kali.org use the  [mirrorbrain](http://mirrorbrain.org/)  redirector to redirect your http request to the best mirror colse to you , it is an official kali linux mirror.

You can use the following command to see where you are being redirected :

```
curl -sI http://http.kali.org/README
```

Comment: But sometimes we dont trust other mirrors. How to avoid such domain redirection with apt?